# ADT 22.0.0 creates empty project

Tags: android, adt

I updated my sdk tools to r22 and adt to 22.0.0 and now I can not create a new project.
In the project wizard I have reached upto last screen and clicked finish button.But clicking finish does not dismiss the wizard window,finish button is still enabled and an empty project is created.
I am using eclipse indigo on windows 8.

[image]

The empty project :

[image]

Comment: I'm having exact same problem now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few bizarre issues in 22.0.0 SDK & ADT.
They have released an update 22.0.1 for SDK and ADT 22.0.1 which fixed most of the issues..
Please try that..

Comment: tried that,but same problem.in fact I initially had this problem with sdk 20 -> upgraded to 22,same problem ->upgraded to 22.0.1,same problem :(

Comment: please check the .log file for exceptions present under workspace/.metadata directory.. That will help you to proceed further..